# PHP: Undefined offset: 3 - preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, url

I have URL structure from example:

http://www.example.com/directory/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1/

My Regex is:

```
preg_match_all("/([^\/.]+?)(?:-vs-|\.\w+$)/", $html, $matches);
```

Expected result:

```
some-text-a1
sec-text-b2
third-text
last-text-c1
```

Result I got:

```
some-text-a1
sec-text-b2
third-text
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in F:\xampp\htdocs\url.php on line 41
```

Full code:

```
$html = "http://www.example.com/directory/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1/";
preg_match_all("/([^\/.]+?)(?:-vs-|\.\w+$)/", $html, $matches);

$prvi = "some-text-a1";
$drugi = "sec-text-b2";
$treci = "third-text";
$cetvrti = "last-text-c1";

echo "URL: ".$html."<br>";

if($prvi == $matches[1][0]){echo "1st O.K. - ".$prvi." = ".$matches[1][0]."<br>";}
if($drugi == $matches[1][1]){echo "2nd O.K. - ".$drugi." = ".$matches[1][1]."<br>";}
if($treci == $matches[1][2]){echo "3rd O.K. - ".$treci." = ".$matches[1][2]."<br>";}
if($cetvrti == $matches[1][3]){echo "4th O.K. - ".$cetvrti." = ".$matches[1][3]."<br>";}
```

Ideas what am I missing? I suppose the ending slash / is the problem within my regex.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use `var_dump` to look what you actually have in `$matches`. http://php.net/var_dump

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "some-text-a1-vs-" [1]=> string(15) "sec-text-b2-vs-" [2]=> string(14) "third-text-vs-" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(12) "some-text-a1" [1]=> string(11) "sec-text-b2" [2]=> string(10) "third-text" } }

Comment: See, you have no third element.

Comment: So, my regex is wrong written?

Comment: Wrong written or you expect the wrong thing.

Comment: What is the `\w+` supposed to match in your expression? It causes the last section of the URL to not match at all. The `.` matches the trailing slash (although you shouldn't escape it) and then the expression expects at least one word character before the end of the line, of which there is none because the end of the line is already reached.

Comment: Yes, regex is wrong. https://regex101.com/r/aP9eP8/1

Comment: Means that \w+ would work in case if the ending is like .html (not /)?

Comment: Which part of the regex should I change to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<=vs-)(.*?)(?=-vs)|(?<=\/)([^\/]*?)(?=-vs)|(?<=vs-)(.*?)(?=\/|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ3cT9/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?<=…)`: Positive lookbehind [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wU2aD6/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`(?=…)`: Positive lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cV6wG7/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`$`: End of string or end of line depending on multiline mode [sample](https://regex101.com/r/eC5iY3/1)

PHP:

```
<?php
$re = "/(?<=vs-)(.*?)(?=-vs)|(?<=\\/)([^\\/]*?)(?=-vs)|(?<=vs-)(.*?)(?=\\/|$)/"$
$str = "http://www.example.com/directory/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-t$

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some-text-a1
    [1] => sec-text-b2
    [2] => third-text
    [3] => last-text-c1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach - using the **parse_url** and **explode** functions.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/directory/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1/';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

var_dump($parsedUrl);

$path = explode('/',trim($parsedUrl['path'],'/'));

var_dump($path);

if (is_array($path) && $path[0] === 'directory') {
        if (isset($path[1])) {
                $vs = explode('-vs-',$path[1]);
                var_dump($vs);
        }
}
```

Comment: `parse_url` has a second parameter to only get the part you are interested by as a string.

Comment: Thanks for idea with explode() function!